# Java: Не выводится массив внутри другого массива в JSON

Tags: java, json, spring, spring-mvc, spring-jpa

Всем доброго дня!
Я использую: `Java + Spring framework + Postgresql`. У меня есть 3 таблицы в базе данных, я хочу вывести все 3 таблицы в одном большом JSON'e.
Сейчас у меня JSON выводится так:

> [{"id":1,"name":"menu1","category":[]},{"id":2,"name":"menu2","category":[]}]

Почему-то массив `category` пустой, хотя в нем должны быть записи.

Код:
Сущности:

**Menu.java:**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "menu")
public class Menu {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "increment")
    @GenericGenerator(name= "increment", strategy= "increment")
    @Column(name = "id", length = 6, nullable = false)
    private long id;

    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "menu", fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    private List<Categories> category;

    //GETTERS AND SETTERS
```

**Categories.java:**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "categories")

public class Categories {

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "category", fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    private List<Dish> dish;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "menu")
    private Menu menu;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "increment")
    @GenericGenerator(name = "increment", strategy = "increment")
    private long id;

    @Column(name = "title_ru", nullable = false, length = 50)
    private String titleRu;

    @Column(name = "title_eng", nullable = false, length = 50)
    private String titleEng;

    @Column(name = "url", nullable = false, length = 150)
    private String url;

    @Column(name = "img_url", nullable = false, length = 150)
    private String imageUrl;

    @Column(name = "weight", nullable = false, length = 5)
    private int weight;

    @Column(name = "status", nullable = false, length = 2)
    private int status;

    public List<Dish> getDishes() {
        return dish;
    }

    @JsonIgnore
    public Menu getMenu() {
        return menu;
    }
```

**Dish.java**

```
 @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "category")
    private Categories category;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "increment")
    @GenericGenerator(name = "increment", strategy = "increment")
    @Column(name = "id", length = 6, nullable = false)
    private long id;

    @Column(name = "title_ru", nullable = false, length = 50)
    private String titleRu;

    @Column(name = "title_eng", nullable = false, length = 50)
    private String titleEng;

    @Column(name = "description_ru", nullable = false, length = 500)
    private String descriptionRu;

    @Column(name = "description_eng", nullable = false, length = 500)
    private String descriptionEng;

    @Column(name = "url", nullable = false, length = 150)
    private String url;

    @Column(name = "img_url", nullable = false, length = 150)
    private String imgUrl;

    @Column(name = "weight", nullable = false, length = 5)
    private int weight;

    @Column(name = "status", nullable = false, length = 2)
    private int status;

    @JsonIgnore
    public Categories getDishCategory() {
        return category;
    }
```

**Controller:**

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/menu", method = RequestMethod.GET)
@ResponseBody
public List<Menu> getAllMenu() {
    return service.getAllMenu();
}
```

**Service:**

```
public List<Menu> getAllMenu() {
    return menuRepository.findAll();
}
```

В чем проблема? Как ее решить? Объясните пожалуйста простыми словами, для новичка.

Comment: Как данные выбираются из базы? Откуда у вас уверенность в том, что subcategory должен быть заполнен?

Comment: Что вы имеете в виду под "как данные выбираются из базы" ? Вы хотите увидеть таблицу и связи в postgresql?

Comment: А где, собсна, в классах находится subcategory? Я вот не вижу в упор :)

Comment: @ВиталийБелоусов я хочу увидеть, что данные там есть после того, как они вытаскиваются из базы

Comment: поправил, не subcategory, а category

Comment: да, они вытаскиваются, но по другой ссылке, где только все категории (позже скину ссылку)

Comment: http://139.59.164.239:8080/tubeserver/menu
http://139.59.164.239:8080/tubeserver/categories
http://139.59.164.239:8080/tubeserver/dishes

Comment: вот тут можно посмотреть как выводятся они по отдельности

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Разобрался. Проблема была в том, что я в БД неправильно создал таблицу и настроил связи. Доверьте это дело лучше самой программе! Создайте базу, но не создавайте таблицы, просто задеплойте сервер и выполните запрос перейдя по ссылке в контроллере.